# What is the scalar field the integral of which gradient norm is equal to the surface area of the surface that the scalar field represent?

Tags: vector-analysis, implicit-function

Assume I have a scalar function $\phi(p): p \in \Omega \subset \mathcal{R}^3 \to \mathcal{R}$. I would like to use it to represent a 2D surface. For example, if $\phi(\cdot)$ is a signed distance function (SDF), then $\phi(p)=0$ represents a 2D surface.

Now, I would like to define the surface area over $\phi(\cdot)$. I would like to have $\int_\Omega |\nabla\phi(p)|dp = A$, where $A$ is the surface area of the surface that $\phi(p)=0$ represents. SDF does satisfy this requirement, as $|\nabla\phi(p)|=1$ everywhere. I am wondering what $\phi(\cdot)$ satisfy such a property. Is there an standard name of this function?

Comment: $|\nabla\phi|\equiv 1$ is the [eikonal equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_distance_function) that is satisfied by the signed distance function of a point to a subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb R^3\,.$ Should then the integral not be the *volume* of $\Omega\,?$

Comment: I think so. I would like to have a different scalar function $\phi$ such that $\phi(p)=0$ represents the surface, the same as how SDF represents a surface. However, I also want to have the integral of the gradient norm of $\phi$ is the *area* of the surface rather than the volume of the domain. Does such $\phi$ exist?